# C Program Exercise. Simple transaction report

Tags: c

Question : Program that asks the user to enter  an item price value  and then show how to pay that amount using the smallest number of $ 50,$20, $10,$5, and $1 bills consist.

Example Output:

```
Enter Price: 187
Enter Amount to pay: 500
Change is : 313

(6)$50 (1)$10 (3)$1
(0)$20 (0)$5
```

---

Here's my code: hope you help me , I am having a hard to in knowing the right formula for it..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define p printf
#define s scanf
#define g gotoxy

main()
{
    clrscr();
    int c1,c2,c3,c4,c5;
    int price,amount;
    float change;
    p("Enter Price: ");s("%d",&price);
    p("Enter amount: ");s("%d",&amount);
    change=amount-price;
    p("Change is : %f ",change);
    c1=(change/50);
    c2=(0);
    c3=(change/change);
    c4=(0);
    c5=(change/change)+2;
    g(5,5);p("(%d) Php 50",c1);
    g(5,6);p("(%d)  Php 20",c2);
    g(18,5);p("(%d)Php 10 \t",c3);p("(%d)Php 1",c5);
    g(18,6);p("(%d) Php  5 ",c4);


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? It sounds like it...

Comment: Tip # 1:  Whatever may be wrong with your code, don't shorten names using macros.  `#define p printf` is absolutely not a good idea.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Next time click on that button with the zeroes and ones to format your code.

Comment: We know you want help; that's why your posting. A more appropriate subject might be "Formula for working out payment details in C (homework)"

Comment: Please, please, never use two or more statements on one line! Especially without a space after the semicolon. I'd help, but I just can't read the code. Formatting is very important in programming.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track:

`change` should be a `int` too (that means you should change %f to %d).  You would then correctly determine the number of 50's (note that integer division in C truncates).  You should look at % (modulus operator) to get the remaining amount of changes after the 50's are dealt with:

Using your example:

change = 313
fifties = 313/50 (6)
change %= 50 (13)

That means set `change` to the remainder after dividing itself by 50 (change = change % 50)

twenties = change / 20 (0)
change %= 20 (13)

tens = change / 10 (1)
change %= 10 (3)

This should give you the basic idea of the code you need.  You just continue this pattern in order of decreasing denomination.

As noted, use better variable names, don't use those defines, and generally stick to one statement per line (add a newline after semi-colons).  This will make your code more readable.  You're also using more parentheses than needed, but that's not a big deal.

Comment: What if i change my Price to 500? and amount to 1000; should i change my formula too?.. sorry newbie.. 

//Wrong Output (o_O) got a $13 over..
Enter Price: 500
Enter Amount to pay: 1000
Change is : 500

(10)$50 (1)$10 (3)$1
(0)$20 (0)$5

Comment: No, the formula is the same for all prices and amounts.  This is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest define an array which holds the bill denominations, and an initially empty array of bill counts:

```
 int denoms[5] = {50, 20, 10, 5, 1};
 int bills[5] =  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

 for(int i =0; i < 5; ++i)
 {
     bills[i] = /* do something interesting with denoms[i] here */
     change = /* more work for you here */
 }

 /* output answer */
 for(int i =0; i < 5; ++i)
 {
     if (bills[i] > 0)
          p("{%d)$%d", bills[i], denoms[i]);
 }
 p("\n");
 for(int i =0; i < 5; ++i)
 {
     if (bills[i] == 0)
          p("{%d)$%d", bills[i], denoms[i]);
 }
 p("\n");
```

Comment: i guess using for loop is not intended in this exercise cause my professor is still not teaching us conditional statements..

Answer (score 0):

```
void changeloop(int* change, int* counter, int amount) {
    while (*change > amount) {
        (*counter)++;
        (*change) -= amount;
    }
}
int main() {
    clrscr();
    int price; printf("Enter Price: "); scanf("%d", &input);
    int amount; printf("Enter Amount: "); scanf("%d", &amount);
    int change = amount - price;
    int fifties, twenties, tens, fives, ones;
    fifties = twenties = tens = fives = ones = 0;
    changeloop(&change, &fifties, 50);
    changeloop(&change, &twenties, 20);
    changeloop(&change, &tens, 10);
    changeloop(&change, &fives, 5);
    changeloop(&change, &ones, 1);
    printf("Fifties: %d\n", fifties);
    printf("Twenties: %d\n", twenties);
    printf("Tens: %d\n", tens);
    printf("Fives: %d\n", fives);
    printf("Ones: %d\n", ones);
    getch();
    return;
}
```

There's work to do, like input validation and error handling. But the basics are here. The code could be refactored to be much more extensible... but meh.

Comment: here's the Output :
Example:
Enter Price : 187
Enter Amount: 500
fifties =584  <--- 500+ fifties? heheh
Twenties: 1
tens : 0
fives : 1
Ones : 3

Comment: Then you screwed up. Mine gives 6/0/1/0/2, which is obviously not quite right. I guess that you might actually have to try to solve the problem.